# Prove or disprove that the difference of the squares of two odd numbers is always divisible by 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove that the difference of the squares of two odd numbers is always divisible by 4.

No idea how to use the proving method to solve this.

Comment: try some examples.

Comment: once you've done that, show that the difference between odd squares is divisible by $8$ to make sure you understand what is going on

Answer (score 4):

An odd number: $2n+1$. Another odd number: $2m+1$. If you substract: $(2n+1)^2-(2m+1)^2$, do you get a multiple of $4$?

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. I get $4(n^2 + n - m^2 - m)$

Comment: I'm assuming that is the end of my working out and proves it is divisible by 4?

Comment: @Jamboo: Yes, that is enough to prove it.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You can factor the difference of two squares as
$$
a^2 - b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)
$$
If $a$ and $b$ are odd, what can we say about $a \pm b$?

Answer (score 2):

Even more is true:
The difference is divisible by $8$.

As Mario G showed,

$\begin{align*}
(2n+1)^2-(2m+1)^2&=[(2n+1)+(2m+1)][(2n+1)-(2m+1)]\\
&=(2n+2m+2)(2n-2m)\\
&=4(n+m+1)(n-m)\\
&=4((n-m)+2m+1)(n-m)
\qquad \text{(this line added)}\\
\end{align*}
$

The two factors
$(n-m)+2m+1$
and
$n-m$
differ by an odd number
($2m+1$),
so they have opposite parity.
Therefore,
one of them is even,
so their product is even
so
$4((n-m)+2m+1)(n-m)$
is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $2n+1$ and $2m+1$ the odd numbers, $n,m\in \mathbb{Z}$ then
\begin{align*}
(2n+1)^2-(2m+1)^2&=[(2n+1)+(2m+1)][(2n+1)-(2m+1)]\\
&=(2n+2m+2)(2n-2m)\\
&=4(n+m+1)(n-m)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

An odd number is congruent to $1$ or $3$ modulo $4$, hence the square of an odd number is congruent to $1$, and the difference of the squares of two odd numbers is congruent to $1-1=0$, i.e. the difference  is a multiple of $4$.